# Deployment PHP gitlab webhook gone wrong

Tags: php, git, shell, deployment, gitlab

I've managed from each pull my server send me a notification. My php script, execute a shell script who is responsible to update my repos, but I'm getting this message

Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

These are my files:

PHP: https://gist.github.com/rodreego/567176913cbe9d925907

Shell: https://gist.github.com/rodreego/964bd48287bff4eafc8a

I've tried to log my user who's executing this shell script, but he's coming blank. Is there something to do with it? I mean, If I run my scripts from my prompt shell, work fine, but when I attempt deploy from server notification, doesn't.

Comment: You probably need to configure your web server to accept the https connection. I have a vague remembering of something along those lines but can't recall any details.

Comment: Actually, Thomas, my server is receiving my request. I said that because the message is logged after my server receive the webhook from my gitlab server.

Comment: Yeah. I was just reviewing your question and tried chipping in an idea - hence the comment and not an answer :-)